# Is it possible to create a dynamic enum

Tags: solidity

Is it possible to create, or populate an enum based on a constructors parameter? Or is it possible to append items to an enum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Enums are types, and solidity is a statically-typed language.

I'm not sure what you are attempting with this, but you may be able to achieve the same thing with mappings, using an int as a key. Alternately, you may be able to create an enum with all possible entries, and only use the relevant ones.

Comment: New to solidity and trying to code some contracts to understand how things work. I'm trying to write a reusable version of the StateMachine contract described in solidity's Common Patterns, where I can inherit from the contract but use a custom set of stages. http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/common-patterns.html

Comment: I think solidity isn't really set up for that kind of thing. A more common approach would be to find a common set of stages, then have each subcontract use different logic to transition between them.